# How to explicitly timeout a Django API request?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, timeout, gunicorn

I want to detect the time taken by an API request in my django application and then explicitly return a 503 error if it reaches the limit.

I already have a limit on gunicorn level, however I want another layer on top of gunicorn timeout which should timeout before gunicorn.

The reason for doing this is to group together and fix every endpoint that throws this custom timeout error/exception.

There is no library support as of yet for django however this is possible in FastAPI using asyncio

`await asyncio.wait_for(call_next(request), timeout=settings.TIMEOUT_SETTINGS)`

For Django I've tried multiple options,

**First one was using multiprocessing and multithreading
**

```
class RequestTimeoutMiddleware:
    def __init__(
        self, get_response, timeout_seconds=settings.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS
    ):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.timeout_seconds = timeout_seconds

    def request_timeout_timer(self, request_completed):
        """
        Child timer process to timeout the request
        """
        elapsed_time = 0
        timeout_seconds = self.timeout_seconds
        while (
            elapsed_time < timeout_seconds and not request_completed.is_set()
        ):
            time.sleep(1)
            elapsed_time += 1

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(
                {
                    "detail": REQUEST_TIMEOUT_ERROR,
                    "processing_time": elapsed_time,
                }
            ),
            status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
            content_type="application/json",
        )

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Create a ThreadPoolExecutor with two worker threads
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            request_completed = threading.Event()

            # Submit both functions to be executed by the threads
            timeout_thread = executor.submit(
                self.request_timeout_timer, request_completed
            )
            request_thread = executor.submit(self.get_response, request)

            # Wait for both threads to complete and get the results
            futures = [timeout_thread, request_thread]
            done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(
                futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED
            )

            # Check which function finished first and return its response
            if timeout_thread in done:
                # request will be timed out
                return timeout_thread.result()
            else:
                # set the shared flag, so that timer thread can exit
                request_completed.set()
                # return API request response
                return request_thread.result()
```

**Then i've tried using a python library called timeout-decorator
**

NOTE: the library has support for using os-signals to perform timeout, however it does not work in the timeout and throws error saying "this OS signal can only be set in the main thread"

With multiprocessing it works fine.

```
@contextmanager
def apply_timeout_decorator():
    timeout_function = timeout(
        settings.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
        timeout_exception=TimeoutException,
        use_signals=False,
    )
    yield timeout_function


class RequestTimeoutMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response, timeout_seconds=settings.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.timeout_seconds = timeout_seconds

    def __call__(self, request):
        if settings.ENVIRONMENT in [settings.PRODUCTION, settings.STAGING]:
            start_time = time.time()
            try:
                with apply_timeout_decorator() as timeout_decorator:
                    response = timeout_decorator(self.get_response)(request)
            except TimeoutException as e:
                elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                return HttpResponse(
                    json.dumps(
                        {
                            "detail": e.default_detail,
                            "processing_time": elapsed_time,
                        }
                    ),
                    status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
                    content_type="application/json",
                )
            return response
        else:
            # disable middleware for tests
            return self.get_response(request)
```

What is the best approach here while limiting any downsides?

Also, using the library timeout-decorator with signals. Is this signal set on the gunicorn level thread? The signal that we get from gunicorn is SIG_ABORT